# Como Reverter uma animação (executar ela ao inverso) via xaml puro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Fiz uma animação Storyboard AbrirMenuzin e ate ai tudo bem, já fiz isso antes de reverter a animação pelo c#

```
//pode estar errado mas foi mais ou menos isso
sb = (Storyboard)Resources["Animaçao"];
sb.AutoReverse = true;
sb.Begin();
sb.Seek(TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), TimeSeekOrigin.Duration);
```

Isso funciona +- mas da pra usar, mas como faço para fazer essa animação executar ao contrario (dar reverse nela) pelo puro xaml.

Onde Parei:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Collapsed">
<SeekStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="AbrirMenuzin" Offset="0" Origin="BeginTime"/>
</EventTrigger>
```

Ps: não quero saber de duplicar/criar outro storyboard, e sim somente dar reverse no storyboard existente.

Comment: Tu precisas de colocar no elemento da animação a opção autoreverse=true, não é na storyboard.

Comment: tem como eu fazer o autoreverse=true apenas na utilização do storyboard? porque tipo eu preciso de manter essa do jeito que está e somente na hora do play ela dar reverse.